# General vs simple list

Tags: list, scheme

What is the difference between simple integer list, general integer list and list in Scheme?

As far as I know list can be created like

```
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

But how can I create general or simple integer list?

Comment: Where have you come across those terms?

Answer (score 1):

A list in scheme can hold any data type; essentially they are all 'general'

```
(list 0 1 '#(0 1) '(0 1) "01" 'zero-one #\0 #\1 '((0) (1)) #t)
```

You can call something 'simple' if you want to but that term is not part of Scheme's definition.